# I'm having hard time bulkifying a code that attach similar deals to an opportunity when is created

Tags: trigger, bulkification

the parameters are:

- amount within 10% of difference
- closed won last year
- Same industry

I'm having hard time since is I have to validate 3 parameters instead one. Below you have the non-bulkified code

```
ComparableOpps on Opportunity (after insert) {

    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
        // Query account info for our opp
        Opportunity oppWithAccountInfo = [SELECT Id,
                                         Account.Industry
                                     FROM Opportunity
                                     WHERE Id = :opp.Id
                                     LIMIT 1];

        // Declaring variables
        Decimal minAmount = opp.Amount * 0.9;
        Decimal maxAmount = opp.Amount * 1.1;

        // Search for comparable opps
        List<Opportunity> comparableOpps = [SELECT Id
                                       FROM Opportunity
                                      WHERE Amount >= :minAmount
                                        AND Amount <= :maxAmount
                                        AND Account.Industry = :oppWithAccountInfo.Account.Industry\
                                        AND StageName = 'Closed Won'
                                        AND CloseDate >= LAST_N_DAYS:365
                                        AND Owner.Position_Start_Date__c < LAST_N_DAYS:365\
                                        AND Id != :opp.Id];
         System.debug('Comparable opp(s) found: ' + comparableOpps);

        // For each comparable opp, create a Comparable__c record
        List<Comparable__c> junctionObjsToInsert = new List<Comparable__c>();
        for (Opportunity comp : comparableOpps) {
            Comparable__c junctionObj             = new Comparable__c();
            junctionObj.Base_Opportunity__c       = opp.Id;
            junctionObj.Comparable_Opportunity__c = comp.Id;
            junctionObjsToInsert.add(junctionObj);
        }
        insert junctionObjsToInsert;
    }
}
```

Comment: What part are you struggling with? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### below you have the improved version of the code.

```
trigger Comparables on Opportunity (after insert) {

Date d = System.today().addDays(-365);

Map<Id, String> mapIdToIndustries = new Map<Id, String>();
List<Comparable__c> comparablesToInsert = new List<Comparable__c>();

//Querying all the opportunites in Trigger.new and adding the values to the Map ID-Industry
for(Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id, Amount, Account.Industry, Industry__c FROM Opportunity
                                                                       WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]) {
    mapIdToIndustries.put(opp.Id, opp.Account.Industry);
}

System.debug(mapIdToIndustries);

//Quering all the matching opportunities with matching industries to the ones in Trigger.New
List<Opportunity> matchingOpps = [SELECT Id, CloseDate, Account.Industry, Name, Amount FROM Opportunity 
                                                                                      WHERE CloseDate > :d
                                                                                        AND Account.Industry IN :mapIdToIndustries.values()
                                                                                        AND Id NOT IN :Trigger.new]; 
System.debug('These are the matching opps: ' + matchingOpps);

//Looping all the Opps in Trigger.new 
for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
    System.debug(opp);
//For each Opp in Trigger.new loop all the matching opps and create a Comparable__c object if they have the same industries and similar amount
    for(Opportunity matchingOpp : matchingOpps) {
        if(matchingOpp.Amount != null && opp.Amount != null) {
            if(opp.Industry__c == matchingOpp.Account.Industry) {
                if(matchingOpp.Amount > opp.Amount*0.9 && matchingOpp.Amount < opp.Amount*1.1) {

                    Comparable__c comp = new Comparable__c();
                    comp.Base_Opportunity__c = opp.Id;
                    comp.Comparable_Opportunity__c = matchingOpp.Id;
                    comp.Name = matchingOpp.Name;

                    System.debug('this is tne matching opp ' + matchingOpp);

                    comparablesToInsert.add(comp);//adding the Comparable__c to the list
                }
            }
        }    

    }
}
System.debug('These are the comps to insert ' + comparablesToInsert);
//Inserting all the records in the list
insert comparablesToInsert;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

There are quite things wrong in your code:-

1. Executing a SOQL query inside the for loop which will make your code execution failed by hitting governer limit soon.
2. Nested for loop will cause apex CPU time limit exception in dealing with bulk data. You can use Maps instead of that to avoid the unnecessary operation of irrelevant data.
3. You have DML statement inside the for loop which will again throw the exception.

   Refer this to get more understanding on best practices to bulkify the code:- [Best Practice: Bulkify Your Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code)

Or you can start from scratch using [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com) and [Apex developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm).